# How to change element's container without re-rending and thus, resetting, state

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I have a component, "Spreadsheet", that is grabbing something from an API, but then I want to hide the side navigation bar, "SideNav", once the data is fetched. The only way I can seem to do this with conditional rendering but the first condition is wrapped in an accordion so it might be too caught up in-between tags for conditional rendering to work. The conditional rendering is resetting my component and hence the data fetched is lost. Wondering how to conditionally render something without losing its state. P.S. the element is a  from React-router so maybe that has something to do with it. Here's the code:

```
render(){
 let Spreadsheet =
            <Route
                path="/spreadsheet"
                render={(props) =>
                    <Spreadsheet
                        selectedStation={this.state.selectedStation}
                        stationOptions={this.state.stationOptions}
                        start={this.state.start}
                        end={this.state.end}
                        data={this.data}
                        statusOptions={this.statusOptionsWithoutRaw}
                        dataSegments={this.state.dataSegments}
                        userSandboxes={this.state.userSandboxes}
                        refreshUserSandboxes={this.getUserSandboxes}
                        showSideNav={this.state.showSideNav}
                        toggleSideNav={(showSideNav) => this.setState({ showSideNav })}
                    />}
            />
return(
    <Container fluid={true}>
                    {this.state.showSideNav ?
                        <Row className="row--margin">
                            <Col md={2}>
                                <SideNav
                                    stations={this.state.station}
                                    setTab={this.setTab}
                                    handleStation={this.handleStation}
                                    stationOptions={this.state.stationOptions}
                                    userSandboxes={this.state.userSandboxes}
                                />
                            </Col>
                            <Col md={10}>
                                <div className="accordion" id="page">
                                    <Card>
                                        <Card.Header className="accordionTitle" as={Button} variant="link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#station">
                                            Station: {this.state.selectedStation && this.state.selectedStation.value}
                                        </Card.Header>
                                        <Card.Body id="station" className="collapse show card-body" data-parent="#page">
                                            {Spreadsheet}
                                        </Card.Body>
                                    </Card>
                                    <Card>
                                        <Card.Header className="accordionTitle" as={Button} variant="link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#analysis">
                                            Analysis Package:
                                        </Card.Header>
                                        <Card.Body id="analysis" className="collapse card-body" data-parent="#page">
                                            <AnalysisPackage />
                                        </Card.Body>
                                    </Card>
                                    <Card>
                                        <Card.Header className="accordionTitle" as={Button} variant="link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#moreInfo">
                                            Click for More Station Information:
                                        </Card.Header>
                                        <Card.Body id="moreInfo" className="collapse card-body" data-parent="#page">
                                            Hello! I'm another body
                                        </Card.Body>
                                    </Card>
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        :
                        <Row className="row--margin">
                            {Spreadsheet}
                        </Row>
                    }
                </Container>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you're basically unmounting and mounting `Spreadsheet` again. Is that what you really want?

If all you want is to hide the sidebar, why not put the conditional exclusively on it? Like

```
Row className="row--margin">
                            <Col md={2}>
                                {this.state.showSideNav && ( <-- LIKE THIS
                                 <SideNav
                                    stations={this.state.station}
                                    setTab={this.setTab}
                                    handleStation={this.handleStation}
                                    stationOptions={this.state.stationOptions}
                                    userSandboxes={this.state.userSandboxes}
                                 />
                                 )}
                            </Col>
                            <Col md={10}>
                                <div className="accordion" id="page">
                                    <Card>
                                        <Card.Header className="accordionTitle" as={Button} variant="link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#station">
                                            Station: {this.state.selectedStation && this.state.selectedStation.value}
                                        </Card.Header>
                                        <Card.Body id="station" className="collapse show card-body" data-parent="#page">
                                            {Spreadsheet}
                                        </Card.Body>
                                    </Card>
                                    <Card>
                                        <Card.Header className="accordionTitle" as={Button} variant="link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#analysis">
                                            Analysis Package:
                                        </Card.Header>
                                        <Card.Body id="analysis" className="collapse card-body" data-parent="#page">
                                            <AnalysisPackage />
                                        </Card.Body>
                                    </Card>
                                    <Card>
                                        <Card.Header className="accordionTitle" as={Button} variant="link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#moreInfo">
                                            Click for More Station Information:
                                        </Card.Header>
                                        <Card.Body id="moreInfo" className="collapse card-body" data-parent="#page">
                                            Hello! I'm another body
                                        </Card.Body>
                                    </Card>
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
```

Comment: That's the ideal solution, but the problem is the surrounding/parent <Card/> element. I'm not sure how to conditionally render that without un-mounting/remounting spreadsheet. You are right about the sideNav though; if it was just that, it would work fine.